# How to view defuns in file order?

Tags: imenu, defun

I think I'm missing something about `imenu`. I'm interested in viewing the top-level definitions in file order. When I run `imenu` I get a prompt in the minibuffer that says `Index item:`. If I then hit `TAB` I go into a `*Completions*` buffer, where the defuns are sorted alphabetically, not in file order.

In the section of the manual on imenu (§27.2.3) it talks about `imenu-sort-function`, but I gather that does not govern the completions buffer.

Is there a way to simply view the defuns in file order?

Comment: FWIW if you use the menu bar, the imenu entries are in file order by default.

Comment: Otherwise I assume it's just `completing-read` sorting things.  E.g. `(completing-read "?" '("a" "c" "b"))` will offer you a, b, c, in that order.

Comment: @phils Thanks, I think I understand how it's supposed to work now. Strangely, however, for me the imenu entries in the menu bar are not in file order. All the entities that have submenus are grouped first, and then the secondary key is file order. I'd rather not use that grouping. Any ideas? (The value of `imenu-sort-function` is `nil` for me currently.)

Comment: I've not looked into it, sorry -- I almost never use imenu from the menu bar, and I've never wanted things in file order.  There's probably something else which is better suited to your requirement than imenu, but I don't know what.  On the rare occasions I want to see a list of definitions like that, I use `occur` with a regexp matching the definitions.

Comment: Maybe `outline-minor-mode` (see `C-h i g (emacs)Outline Mode`) or some third-party package along similar lines would be useful?

Comment: @phils Thanks, `occur` is a good idea.

Comment: FWIW, [`imenu+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/imenu%2b.el) has a **Toggle Sorting** menu item. When sorting is turned off the menu entries are in buffer/file order.

Comment: @Drew Thank you. Cool extension. Weirdly, that has the same grouping property for me (all entities w submenus are grouped first.) Now I'm starting to think I have some setting somewhere that's causing this, since other people reportedly get simple file order from `imenu+` and `imenu`. Hmmm

Comment: (Yes, turning off sorting does not remove grouping into submenus.)

Comment: I said "…are grouped first" when more clear would have been "…are sorted first".

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages which will *show* you a list of the things imenu knows about, instead of *prompting* you for one. Give `imenu-list` a try, for example.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Somehow this avoids the undesired sorting behavior also.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the order of menu items is by default what you request: the order of the targets in the buffer/file.

Try redefining (or advising) `imenu--split-menu` to just return a list of its args, that is, the main Imenu title followed by the list of menu items:

```lisp
(defun imenu--split-menu (menulist title) (cons title (copy-sequence menulist)))
```

That prevents splitting of the main Imenu menu into submenus.

You can check add a `Defs` menu to the menu-bar with this:

```lisp
(imenu-add-to-menubar "Defs")
```

Comment: Oh, misunderstanding: it's not the presence of submenus I want to avoid (I like the submenus), but rather putting all the menu items with submenus first before all other items (similar to `ls --group-directories-first`), even when they don't come first in the file. I wonder why that's happening

Comment: Submenus can't, themselves be listed in buffer order, because they aren't in the buffer! They gather things from throughout the buffer. The items in a submenu can be sorted or in buffer order, but there's no "buffer order" among the submenus themselves.

Comment: Not putting subdirectories first in a Dired listing is unrelated. Why? Because subdirectories are themselves **in the file listing**. You can put them anywhere, e.g., alphabetically order them along with the non-dir files, or whatever. But Imenu submenus - their names - are nowhere in the buffer.